# Create an instance of a Type, provided as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

The class to instantiate:

```
public class InstantiateMe
{
    public String foo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Some pseudo-code:

```
public void CreateInstanceOf(Type t)
{
    var instance = new t();

    instance.foo = "bar";
}
```

So far I'm figuring that I need to use reflection to get this done, given the dynamic nature of what I want to achieve.

Here's my success criteria's:

- Create an instance of any type
- Create instances of types without having to invoke their constructor
- Access all public properties

I would greatly appreciate some working example-code. I'm not new to C#, but I've never worked with reflection before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd basically need to use Reflection. Use `Activator.CreateInstance()` to construct your type and then call `InvokeMember()` on the type, to set the property:

```
public void CreateInstanceOfType(Type t)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t); // create instance

    // set property on the instance
    t.InvokeMember(
        "foo", // property name
        BindingFlags.SetProperty,
        null,
        obj,
        new Object[] { "bar" } // property value
    );
}
```

To access all the properties of the generic type and set/get them, you can use `GetProperties()` which returns a `PropertyInfo` collection, which you can iterate through:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
{ 
    property.GetValue() // get property
    property.SetValue() // set property
}
```

Also, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx) for more ways of using `InvokeMember()`.

Comment: Docs and Intellisense are doing nothing for me at. Could you provide me with some working code?

Comment: @Wim: `Activator.CreateInstance(T)` is not working when I try to instantiate a parameter-less class. Any ideas?

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) - or simply T obj = new T();

Comment: @Wim: It seems like your code is ignoring the SetProperty binding flag. I get a System.MissingMethodException

Comment: OK - I finally tested it, rather than typing into a HTML textbox. ;-)

Comment: @Wib: Now you broke the dynamic nature of your example--I want the method to be able to instantiate and use properties on _any_ type. Not just a pre-defined one. It should not return anything, just create an instance of a type passed as a parameter: `CreateInstanceOf(Type t) { /* new up type (t). Do stuff with the instance */ }`

Comment: Well, adjust it accordingly, and don't return the type.

Comment: Modified it to add another snippet which goes through all the properties of the type.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Wim. I've edited your answer to better fit the question. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following to actually create the instance.

```
Object t = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

It is not possible however, without generics and constraints to statically access the members as shown in your example.

You could do it with the following though

```
public void CreateInstanceOf<T>() where T : InstantiateMe, new()
{
    T i = new T();
    i.foo = "bar";
}
```

Comment: That would be: T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); ;-)

Comment: It should be T ins = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

Comment: @Wim, Gonzalo, thanks.  Fixed it to use the non-generic CreateInstance method.

Comment: Nice solution, though it seems to defeat the object of using generics, to then restrict it to a single type.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the type you want to instantiate, you can use a generic helper method for that:

```
public static T New() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Else if you are pulling out the type of some where else (like a dynamically loaded assembly) and you have not access to the type directly (it is some sort of meta programming or reflected data) you should use reflection.